# multithreading class vs methods

Tags: python, multithreading, class, methods

I'm starting to write a program that uses threads but after searching how to start threads in Python I have found two methods that accomplish the same thing. There must be a difference or advantage one over the other. Confused which road I should go down.

My thread is going to be ran in the background continuously and never stop until the program is told to by the user. Also one or more arguments will be passed to the thread when started.

one way using classes:

```
from threading import Thread

class myClassA(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            print 'A'

myClassA()
while True:
    pass
```

Second way using methods:

```
from threading import Thread

def runA():
    while True:
        print 'A\n'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = Thread(target = runA)
    t1.setDaemon(True)
    t1.start()
    while True:
        pass
```

Comment: You should use `t1.daemon = True` in your last example.  Make sure you understand the import restrictions mentioned in https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#importing-in-threaded-code before you elect to call `.start()` in the `__init__()` method of a global object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My rule of thumb for using classes is that you shouldn't use them until you find a good use case for them. One use case would be if you wanted to define multiple methods to interact with the thread. But usually developers can't see the future when designing classes so it's better to just code using functions, and when you see a use case for classes refactor your code. What I mean is, you might spend a lot of time designing a class and not even end up using or needing a lot of the functionality you implemented; so you wasted your time and made your code complex for no reason.